# Outlook on Kubuntu 14.0.4 with Wine

Tags: email, wine

I have Kubuntu 14.04 and am mandated by my employer to use Outlook 2013 for company email for "security reasons". I currently solve this problem by having a virtual Windows 7. This seems like a bit of overkill. I have never used wine but in principle it would be an ideal solution. Can somebody please point me to a guide to using Office through wine? I have read that it is buggy on various  posts but they are quite outdated. Does anybody have recent feedback on such an endeavour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [to WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26323) the application will install but it's very likely that it won't run at all.

Your current solution (having Windows in a VM) seems like the more seamless and effective solution to the problem. Unless something change, I recommend using a Virtual Machine instead.

Comment: I am continually amazed that there is not a Linux version of Microsoft Office. Huge client base.

Comment: @Keith they are just not interested.